# Change "next window" keyboard shortcut in GNU screen

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen

I can split my screen window horizontally by typing `Ctrl-A S` (or vertically with `Ctrl+A |`), and then I can switch between windows with `Ctrl-A Tab`.  I'd like to also be able to switch windows with `Ctrl-A o` (to parallel how you can switch windows in emacs with `Ctrl-x o`).  I've tried reading the docs on screen's `bindkey` command, but I find them completely inscrutable. Can anyone help me make this change?  Thank you!

Note: I'm not actually using `Ctrl-A` as my escape key, I've actually set my escape key to backtick, but backticks wreak havok on the formatting on stackchange, so I left the examples using the default `Ctrl-A` escape sequence to make this question easier to type out. I'm assuming the solution shouldn't care about what the escape sequence actually is, so long as I can set the key sequence to change windows to be `<escape sequence> o`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Bind.html#Bind).

Add this to your `.screenrc` file:

```
bind o focus next
```

Comment: Interesting, I had been looking at the docs for 'bindkey' not for 'bind', which now raises the question on what the difference is...

Anyway this suggestion doesn't do exactly what I want.  This gives `Ctrl-A o` the same behavior as `Ctrl-A n`, but I want it to have the same behavior as `Ctrl-A Tab`.  I'm not sure exactly what actual correct terminology for screen is, but this is cycling through what I think of in my head as the 'tabs', but not the 'windows'.

Comment: Looks like maybe the proper terminology is that the 'next' command goes to the next "window" but what I want is the next "region"

Comment: Okay, figured it out, the command I'm looking for is 'focus'.  Anyway, thanks @Timothy Brackett, this comment gave me the clue I needed (use 'bind' not 'bindkey') to be able to figure the rest out from the docs.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I switched to `tmux` years ago, and no longer have `screen` installed on any of my systems.

Comment: Edited answer to show the behavior that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Okay figured it out, the proper invocation is `bind o focus next`

Comment: [so](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/617274/revisions), please delete your this answer and mark @TimothyBrackett's answer as accepted

Comment: He changed his answer to be correct after I posted this.  Now that it's been updated I can take his if that's better.  Although now our discussion in the comments on his answer makes less sense now that the text has been changed...